# Prisma InvalidDatasourceError: Error validating datasource db: the URL must start with the protocol prisma://

Tags: prisma, bun, elysiajs

Question:
I'm encountering an issue with Prisma where I get the error message "InvalidDatasourceError: Error validating datasource db: the URL must start with the protocol prisma://" when running bun dev. Here are the details of my setup:

Environment:
Bun
Elysia
Prisma
MySQL

```
"DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/MyTodoApp"

//schema.prisma:


generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-3.0.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Every time I run bun dev, I encounter this error. However, when I follow the error message's suggestion to add an API key, I can't find any relevant information in the Prisma documentation.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did you try writing the url directly like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = "mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/MyTodoApp"
}
```

If still there is an error, can you share your whole .env file?

Comment: Yes, i tried that, but the same error, my .env looks like                                  PORT=3000 DATABASE_URL=mysql:// JWT_SECRET=“a song lyric”

Comment: Can you copy your prisma schema file and run this: npx prisma init --datasource-provider mysql